# Android - button disappears when resized

Tags: android-view, android, android-button

I am trying to have a button which scales dynamically. At run time, I want its width and height to be 70% of the current size.  However, the button is disappearing.  Here is my code:

```
    Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_transaction);
    btn.setMinWidth(0);
    btn.setMinHeight(0);

    btn.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    int width = btn.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = btn.getMeasuredHeight();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btn.getLayoutParams();

    params.width = (int) .7 * width;
    params.height = (int) .7 * height;

    btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

And the xml:

```
<Button

    android:id="@+id/button_delete_transaction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/add_img"
    android:focusable="false"

    />
```

Comment: you are calling 
v.findViewById(R.id.button_delete_transaction) and the xml shows  android:id="@+id/button_add_transaction"

Are you calling the right, there is some add, delete mistake.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Edited my post with the correct id.

Comment: Is that problem in your code too?

Comment: No, I am using the correct button in my code.

Comment: I think you should use getWidth() and getHeigth() instead of Measured, because the documentation says:"...This is called to find out how big a view should be." and you want to get how big it already is.

Comment: Also it says that are the spaces imposed by the parents and your view is wrapping the content, not influenced by parent, well, that's what I think can be the reason of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Ahh...it is because you are not casting the right thing as an int. You are casting 0.7 as an int (which goes to zero) and then multiplying it, instead of multiplying and then casting. You can use `(int) (.7 * width)` instead of `(int) .7 * width`.

See my example: http://ideone.com/NSGwGF

Anyway, my advice below still stands.

---

Why not use:

```
btn.setWidth((int) Math.round(.7 * width));
btn.setHeight((int) Math.round(.7 * height));
```

instead of:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btn.getLayoutParams();
params.width = (int) .7 * width;
params.height = (int) .7 * height;
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Yes! the problem was with the casting. (However it does not work unless I use LayoutParams. All of this code is in an adapter, so that may be the reason I'm not really sure.)

Comment: Fair enough. May I suggest rounding using Math.round() before casting? This way it will round 239.9 to 240 instead of 239.